# pyrtlsdr installation Windows 10

Tags: python, rtl-sdr, pyrtlsdr

I am trying to install pyrtlsdr, I first installed SDRUno and checked whether my SDRPlay is connected and working fine. That's ok. Then I try to install pyrtlsdr with pip on Windows 10 with Python 3.11.0 [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32.

This sample rise the following error:

```
from rtlsdr import RtlSdr

sdr = RtlSdr()

# configure device
sdr.sample_rate = 2.048e6  # Hz
sdr.center_freq = 70e6     # Hz
sdr.freq_correction = 60   # PPM
sdr.gain = 'auto'

print(sdr.read_samples(512))
```

Error:

```
    C:\Users\python.exe C:\Users\PycharmProjects\sdr\01.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\01.py", line 3, in <module>
    sdr = RtlSdr()
          ^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\env1\Lib\site-packages\rtlsdr\rtlsdr.py", line 133, in __init__
    self.open(device_index, test_mode_enabled, serial_number)
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\env1\Lib\site-packages\rtlsdr\rtlsdr.py", line 171, in open
    raise LibUSBError(result, 'Could not open SDR (device index = %d)' % (device_index))
rtlsdr.rtlsdr.LibUSBError: <LIBUSB_ERROR_IO (-1): Input/output error> "Could not open SDR (device index = 0)"

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

pyrtlsdr only works with RTL2832u.
But to use with SDRPlay you can using library gnuradio or [SoapySDR](https://github.com/pothosware/SoapySDR/wiki/PythonSupport).